# Joomla 2.5 integrating wordpress

Tags: url, joomla, joomla2.5, external

I have a Joomla 2.5 website and I've added a Wordpress blog to it:

htdocs is the joomla site
htdocs/blog is the wordpress blog

I've tried to set up a menu item to point to the blog by setting it up as an external URL:

www.domain.com/blog

However, Joomla keeps throwing an error:

Save failed with the following error: A first level menu item alias cannot be 'our-blog' because 'our-blog' is a sub-folder of your joomla installation folder.

I can't get it to work without hacking the database or the core code.  Is there a simple solution that I'm missing?

Comment: If you are selecting menu item as an external URL, then this error should not come...

Comment: that's what I thought.  I've tried rebuilding the menu but it still comes

Comment: The current Joomla 2.5 sub version is 2.5.19, so check if your Joomla version is 2.5.19, if not please upgrade it.

Comment: I am using the latest version

Answer (score 0):

Have you triple checked that you are indeed selecting the External URL link and not the Menu Item Alias, and that for the URL you are using http://www.domain.com/blog ?[image] .

Also, if you have other menu items pointing to this same blog link, delete them and clear your menu trash.

Good luck!

Comment: definitively using the external URL.  Double and triple checked.

Comment: @user1616338 ... and you've also confirmed there aren't any other menu items pointing to the same blog link? As others have noted, you shouldn't be getting this error so there's something else at play.